# Is the given following statement is true /false relating to homeomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis

Is  the given  following statement istrue /false ?

Given $X = [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ such that  C ={$(x,y) \in  X : xy= 0 $} and D  ={$(x,y) \in X,  x  = {+}^{-} y$  }. Then $C$  is homeomorphic to $D$

First i was drawing the graphs

[image]

From the graph  i noticed that  it will not homomeorphics ...

is it  true /false ?

Pliz help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rotation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ clockwise and then multiplying $x$ and $y$ by $\sqrt2$ respectively seems to be the homeomorphism you are searching for: bijective and bi-continuous.

Comment: im not  getting   can u elaborate  in details...

Comment: To be specific, we map every $(x,y)\in C$ to $(x-y,x+y)$ and verify that $(x-y,x+y)$ is indeed in $D$. In fact, for every $(x,y)\in C$, it's of the form $(x,0)$ or $(y,0)$, so finally its image will turn out to be either $(x,x)$ or $(-y,y)$, which are in $D$.

Comment: thanks @Maduri_